# Ferramenta para calcular o desempenho e/ou consumo energético em um dispositivo móvel

Tags: php, html, aplicação-web, mobile

Olá, estou num projeto que preciso desenvolver alguns aplicativos web para um dispositivo móvel. É para a plataforma Android. E gostaria de uma ferramenta que me de o desempenho dessa aplicação e/ou que me de o consumo energético dessa aplicação.

Comment: Até agora não entendi porque a pergunta seria ampla. Qual parte de *medir consumo energético* é ampla? Pode ser até que não se tenha uma forma de fazer isso, mas é uma pergunta simples e direta.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa utilizar os recursos de baixo nível da plataforma para obter tais informações.

Aqui nesse [link](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power/index.html) existe uma descrição de uma API para análise de consumo de energia do dispositivo. Bem como estatísticas que servirão para o seu projeto.

Bem como valores de consumo para inúmeros componentes do dispositivo.